# how to skip nouveau driver error while installing ubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nouveau

I am installing ubuntu downloaded recently into my pc with GT 240 graphics card.
the installation is hanging .
when pressing alt+sshift +f1 I saw many errors starting with nouveau. 
Killing the installation and trying to restart with nomodeset option from F6 menu .
Still facing the same errors.
I tried also to use skill command to kill nouveau but failed.

Comment: If there is a way to start with basic graphics then it is fine for me at the time

Answer (score 0):

You can not kill or skip nouveau because it is part an integral part of linux kernel, part a module of X server. It goes in separate package but removing it is a really bad idea. You can blacklist nouveau module but this will likely lead to your GUI not booting at all.
You should ask a new question with proper details on the problem, the community will solve it.

Comment: My installation is showing the nouveau driver errors and it is not going further.?

Comment: Unknown errors are solved by unknown means.